# Copy and Paste values from one excel workbook to another

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I tried to record a macro that pasted the values of one workbook into another workbook, however when I do this I get a "run-time error 9 subscript out of range"

I am sure this is just an easy fix, and I am new to macros, so any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
`Sub Refresh()
'
' Refresh Macro
' Update XY Act. Values 2017
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
Windows("XY Update File v2.xlsx").Activate
Selection.Copy
Windows("Engineering XY Chart v2.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: There is so much that would need to be done to make this viable, with a lot of questions as to what specifically you are trying.  The best thing to do is to Google, `copy range from one workbook to another vba` find some code  (And there is a lot out there) that gets close, try to modify it, and come back when it does not work, with more specifics on exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution worked for you.

Comment: Are both workbooks open at the time, and in the same instance of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Its generally better practice to stay away from Activate and Select.

```
'variables
Dim workbook1 As Workbookm, workbook2 As Workbook, filePath1 As String

filePath1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Engineering XY Chart v2.xlsx" 'assuming filepath is the same as macro workbook
filePath2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\XY Update File v2.xlsx" 'assuming filepath is the same as macro workbook

'make references to workbooks
Set workbook1 = Workbook.Open(Filename:=filePath1)
Set workbook2 = Workbook.Open(Filename:=filePath2)

'Copies cell A1 from sheet1 of workbook 2 to cell A1 sheet 1 of workbook 1
workbook1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = workbook2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```